# Two processes into Zenity progress- how to auto close?

Tags: python, bash, zenity

I have a dirty way to show upload speed while my Youtube API uploader script runs, I measure the network output of a specific port, while the upload is in progress. My problem is that the data from the network port continues after the upload so the Zenity progress remains open, and doesnt auto-close - can't figure out how to get around this. I require $upl to pass the youtube ID to another portion of the script, so I'm not sure I quite have that right. (Comments added for clarity)

```
#This is the uploading script
upl=$(python /home/pi/Documents/ytu/yt_up.py --file="${_file}" --title="$finaltitle $xy"  --description="$show_body" --keywords="$yt_tags" --category="28" --privacyStatus="$priv") | \
#This measures upload data rate $xy is the filename
ifstat -S -i eth0 |stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '\r' '\n' |  stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 awk -W interactive '{print "#'$xy' " $2 "kb/s"}' | \
zenity --progress --width 500 --height 25 --title="Uploading to Youtube " \
                    --text="" --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill
```

So my question is how to close the Zenity dialog on completion of the upload?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is the `upl` value, and why is the assignment piped into ifstat. I'm assuming this is a typo, and there is no relationship between the ut_up.py and the progress monitoring, as per description, and that the `upl` is needed down the road.

Consider forking the zenity progress into the backgroud, BEFORE running the uploader. This will make it easier to transfer retain the value of the `upl` variable.

```
#
# Pre-fork the progress bar
#
ifstat -S -i eth0 |
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '\r' '\n' |
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 awk -W interactive '{print "#'$xy' " $2 "kb/s"}' |
  zenity --progress --width 500 --height 25 --title="Uploading to Youtube " \
                    --text="" --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill &
ZENITY_PID=$!

#
# Upload the data, save the result in `upl`
#
upl=$(python /home/pi/Documents/ytu/yt_up.py --file="${_file}" --title="$finaltitle $xy"  --description="$show_body" --keywords="$yt_tags" --category="28" --privacyStatus="$priv")

#
# Kill the progress bar (
#
kill $ZENITY_PID
```

To get the auto-close to work, you will need some way to send '100%' completion rate. This is complex in this case, as the upload process has to stay in the foreground (to set the `upl` variable. Additional information about the python script and the value of `upl` is needed to address this issue.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try that.  $upl ends up being the YoutubeID of the uploaded video, its what's returned after a successful upload - which is then used in other parts of the overall workflow. That python script yt_up.py returns the id

Comment: Could I add a while upl=nothing loop and when it equals something kill the pid?

Comment: In which case what would be the structure of that loop?

Comment: The 'upl=$(...)' will not complete until the python job exit. How will the `while` loop helps ? the progress window will go down when the upload is complete.

Comment: Ok, I guess I I was thinking that it could do nothing until $upl was a value (in which case the upload would have completed)