# kill specific Process inside FIFO with zenity cancel

Tags: python, bash, zenity

I have a process which runs as part of a FIFO pipe

```
FIFO=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $FIFO
(cat $FIFO | zenity --progress \
                    --width 500 --height 25 --title="Uploading to Youtube " \
                    --text='<span font="12" font_weight="bold" foreground="red">'$xy'\n '"$fz"' Youtube Upload: '$fcount' TO GO </span>' --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill) &
upl=$(python /home/pi/Documents/ytu/yt_up.py --file="${_file}" --title="$finaltitle $xy"  --description="$show_body" --keywords="$yt_tags" --category="28" --privacyStatus="$priv")
echo 'Bye bye' > $FIFO
rm -f $FIFO
```

Currently this works great, the Zenity progress stays open while the python script executes and closes.
However I want to be able to abort the process using the cancel button, and have tried this after the code above:

```
FIFO=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $FIFO
(cat $FIFO | zenity --progress \
                    --width 500 --height 25 --title="Uploading to Youtube " \
                    --text='<span font="12" font_weight="bold" foreground="red">'$xy'\n '"$fz"' Youtube Upload: '$fcount' TO GO </span>' --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill) &
upl=$(python /home/pi/Documents/ytu/yt_up.py --file="${_file}" --title="$finaltitle $xy"  --description="$show_body" --keywords="$yt_tags" --category="28" --privacyStatus="$priv")

#updated to show code I am using
if [ "$?" = 1 ] ; then
  sudo pkill -f yt_up.py
fi
echo 'Bye bye' > $FIFO
rm -f $FIFO
```

But the cancel button in the Zenity progress dialog does not seem to trigger the pkill event nor does it seem to throw an error. I have tested that the pkill code works and closes the script when run from the CLI

**Update**: I have now removed the FIFO to see if that makes any difference, also moved to YAD as I can position the dialog window precisely:

```
upl=$(python /home/pi/Documents/ytu/yt_up.py --file="${_file}" --title="$finaltitle $xy"  --description="$show_body" --keywords="$yt_tags" --category="28" --privacyStatus="$priv") | \
                        yad --progress \
                                --button=Cancel:1 --geometry="500x125+138+40" --width=500 --height=25 --title="Uploading to Youtube " \
                                --text='<span font="12" font_weight="bold" foreground="red">'$xy'\n '"$fz"' Youtube Upload: '$fcount' TO GO </span>' --pulsate --auto-close
                           # Cancel from zenity progress bar
                        if [ "$?" =  1 ]; then
                                sudo pkill -f yt_up.py
                                echo "Dialog output=$?"
                         fi
```

But again, the python process is holding up the dialogue output

Comment: `$?` will never be `-1`; it's set to a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Ok, thanks, was just using code from an example elsehwere, changed it to 0 and still not working

Comment: I believe hitting cancel produces an exit status of 1.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but for some reason not working, I mean the zenity progress box closes, but not the python script. So not executing for whatever reason I suspect

Comment: Could it be something to do with the Zenity part happening inside the FIFO so the output is not caught?

Answer (score 0):

There are two processes running, and the main `main` one is waiting for the upload to complete. Consider organizing the code into function to make it easier to control behavior.

Current code examine the status from the upload process, when it complete. Will always indicate success, unless the upload fail. New code check status from the zenity status.

```
FIFO=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $FIFO
function progress {
    cat $FIFO | zenity --progress \
                --width 500 --height 25 --title="Uploading to Youtube " \
                --text='<span font="12" font_weight="bold" foreground="red">'$xy'\n '"$fz"' Youtube Upload: '$fcount' TO GO </span>' --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill

    # Cancel from zenity progress bar
    if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
        pkill -f yt_up.py
    fi
}

progress &

upl=$(python /home/pi/Documents/ytu/yt_up.py --file="${_file}" --title="$finaltitle $xy"  --description="$show_body" --keywords="$yt_tags" --category="28" --privacyStatus="$priv")

#updated to show code I am using
echo 'Bye bye' > $FIFO
rm -f $FIFO
```

Could not test - as required pieces not shared.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have organized the code as suggested it still works!, But it also still fails to shut down the yt_up.py script. However now a keyboard interrupt does kill it off (which it didnt before), previously I used the pkill -f yt_up.py from the CLI

Comment: The yt_up.py process can take some time and it seems that while its doing its thing, the zenity output does not get processed

Comment: Confirmed that the zenity cancel does not get processed until after the yt_up.py process is complete. (I hit cancel and waited for the upload to complete, and the zenity cancel parameter was written to my log after the upload. I guess I need to figure out how to read that concurrently and act apon it.

Comment: @Nowski. It is not possible for me to replicate the whole setup. You have to figure out the correct kill/pkill command. The question implies that the only issue was detecting the Cancel button. Does the pkil works from the command line ?

Comment: @Nowski consider adding "echo" to the script - does the echo prints ?

Comment: Thanks dash-0 - totally understand.
The pkill works fine from CLI, the issue is $? does not get passed from zenity  until yt_up.py has finished. I have added echo `zenity output=$?` and that indeed does output zenity output=1 (once upl has finished) so the cancel button definitely works and so does the function, its just that it does not process until `$upl` has completed even though cancel closes the zenity window. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Nowski. I've compared this to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143763/two-processes-into-zenity-progress-how-to-auto-close - I'm not sure the FIFO was added. There are simpler way to get this done. Do you need the FIFO ?

Comment: I am trying to recall why I need the FIFO -( I first wrote this code a while back - this is a refinement based on in the field feedback) I think its because I need to return a value from `$upl` and have the zenity process as well